# IOS app crashing with my custom splash/launch screen

Tags: ios, react-native

I am developing a React Native Typescript iOS mobile app and it crashes 95% time on launch because of my custom splash/launch screen. I created an empty project and little by little I tested each functionality of my app and saw that it started crashing immediately after implementing my custom splash/launch screen functionality. I have installed the package `react-native-splash-screen@3.3.0` and have even ran commands `cd ios`, `bundle install` and `bundle exec pod install`. I run the app with command: `npx react-native run-ios --device "My Device"`. I have done the following via XCode:

Dragged and dropped an SVG file into the Images section and named it `Splash`.

`LaunchScreen.storyboard`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="21701" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="01J-lp-oVM">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="21678"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="EHf-IW-A2E">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="01J-lp-oVM" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Ze5-6b-2t3">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" image="Splash" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="kAt-3h-SzH">
                                <rect key="frame" x="67" y="269" width="240" height="128"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMinX="YES" widthSizable="YES" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMinY="YES" heightSizable="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            </imageView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="Bcu-3y-fUS"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.098039215686274508" green="0.098039215686274508" blue="0.098039215686274508" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="iYj-Kq-Ea1" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="52.173913043478265" y="375"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="Splash" width="60" height="60"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

`AppDelegate.mm`: Comment: Added the line below

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>

// Added the line below
#import "RNSplashScreen.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"flexbox_tv_mobile";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};
  
  // Added the line below
  bool didFinish = [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  
  // Added the line below
  [RNSplashScreen show];

  // Added the line below
  return didFinish;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

`App.tsx`:

```
...

import SplashScreen from "react-native-splash-screen";

...


    componentDidMount(): void {
        SplashScreen.hide();
    
...
```

- `Xcode Version 14.3 (14E222b)`
- iPhone 8 Plus Device - iOS Version `16.5.1 (c)`

I have uploaded my project files from the `ios` folder into https://snack.expo.dev/@amandeep3/test. Maybe you can download the `test_app` folder and create a new empty react native project `npx react-native init <NAME> --template react-native-template-typescript`, and test my app to see if it crashes on your end?

Comment: can you please share logs you should be getting on xcode while app is crashing

Comment: @RohitSK I don't know how to get logs of an app that hasn't even launched. Metro only shows logs after the splash/launch screen part. Can you guide me on getting the logs as I run the app with command: `npx react-native run-ios --device "My Device"`?

Comment: if you run app using xcode, you can get the logs in the xcode debug window, this will give you exact reason of the crash.

Comment: When I installed the app via Xcode, it didn't crash. But after I close the app and re-opened, it crashes and the logs don't appear.

Comment: as we don't have exact cause of the crash, I would suggest using [```react-native-bootsplash```](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bootsplash) as ```react-native-splash-screen``` does have a lot of crash issues.

Comment: Did you optimize the images at all? Mobile devices sometimes spaz out with optimized images in my experience, for reasons I don't understand.

Comment: I'm using an SVG file now. So I import the SVG file into the Images place and reference it in LaunchScreen.

Comment: I have uploaded my project files from the ios folder into https://snack.expo.dev/@amandeep3/test. Maybe you can download the `test_app` folder and create a new empty react native project `npx react-native init <NAME> --template react-native-template-typescript`, and test my app to see if it crashes?

Answer (score 1):

You can show splash screen like below code snippet. It works fines for the latest React Native Version (0.71.1).

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"reactApp";
  
  [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  [RNSplashScreen show];

  return YES;
}
```

Reason why this happens:
Your Splash Screen should shown after the IOS finishes the launch. In your case, you're showing the Splash Screen before finishing the launch options. RNSplash doesn't know where to get attach before the rootView setup.

Hope you will find this solution insightful.

Source :  https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/606

Comment: Hi, I have written the code in my question the same way as your answer and it is still crashing.

Comment: Okay share your xcode log so we have more idea about issue

Comment: I am not very good with Xcode. Can you guide me to get the logs? I don't have more to share. I made an empty project and only has my splash screen code.

Comment: Just google it's a essay things, open you xcode see canter bottom

Comment: I run the app via Xcode, and in the below panel, I get `All Ouputs`. What should I provide you with?

Comment: Can you try my updated answer, share you crash reason

Comment: Okay, so I changed my code to your answer. I closed Xcode and ran commands: `npm i`, `cd ios`, `bundle install`, `bundle exec pod install`, `cd ..` and `npx react-native run-ios --device "My Device"`. The app crashed after it was installed and auto-launched, and there were no crash logs in Metro, Bundler or any other window. What should I do now?

Comment: It doesn't work if you try to log via the command line, so you will need to run through Xcode so that you can view the log in Xcode.

Comment: Okay, so I ran the app via Xcode and it installed and launched successfully but after I closed the app and re-open it, it crashes. No crash logs appear for re-opening the app. Is there a way to watch an app's logs in Xcode?

Comment: @Jitendrasing, I have uploaded my project files from the `ios` folder into https://snack.expo.dev/@amandeep3/test. Maybe you can download the `test_app` folder and create a new empty react native project `npx react-native init <NAME> --template react-native-template-typescript`, and test my app to see if it crashes?

Comment: @aman what is the version of your Xcode and simulator or device iOs version?

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar I have updated my question with those details.